# Onclick functions working with doubleclick?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have written a code in JavaScript providing `onclick` event, but instead of executing in single click it takes double click to execute it:

```
<­a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="chatWith("arun")>Arun<­/a>

function chatWith(chatuser) {
createChatBox(chatuser);
$("#chatbox_"+chatuser+" .chatboxtextarea").focus();
}

function createChatBox(chatboxtitle,minimizeChatBox) {
if ($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).length > 0) {
    if ($("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('display') == 'none') {
        $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).css('display','block');
        restructureChatBoxes();
    }
    $("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle+" .chatboxtextarea").focus();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your link declaration:

`<­a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="chatWith("arun")>Arun<­/a>`

should be:

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="chatWith('arun')">Arun</a>`

You can't use a **""** pair within another **""**. You need to use ' " " ' or " ' ' ". I'm surprised your link worked at all.
Check out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EQBQp/4/) for a simple fiddle of the onclick event.

Comment: it was only working in mozilla firefox with double click...not in other browsers